# How to implement a switch in spice?

Tags: switches, switching, spice, pspice, hspice

I have designed a circuit where I want to give a pulse of very short duration using a switch. How can I implement it in spice.

Comment: Do you want to use a switch? Why not use a pulse voltage source? Also have a look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372278/spdt-in-ltspice

Comment: Check the use of the time dependent resistor in my answer in [How to simulate simple on/off, Single-Pole-Single-Throw switch?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/450292/200815). It's my favourite way of implementing switches.

Comment: There is the ".Sxxx" component.